# Serving video file to iPhone

Tags: java, javascript, iphone, google-app-engine

I am trying to serve video files from google app engine to iPhone.

If I use `response.sendRedirect` as the code below, everything is working well.

I can download the video file from IE, play on Safari, even on the iPhone simulator.

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {

    response.sendRedirect("/jkl/iyou.mp4");

    }

}
```

However, If I use `request.getRequestDispatcher("/jkl/iyou.mp4").forward(request, response)`, it is only working on IE browser.

If I add `response.setContentLength(711000)` to the code below, it is working on IE and Safari, but not on the iPhone simulator.

```
        public class Test1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
          public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws IOException {

              response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jkl/iyou.mp4").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

The test can be seen at [1]: http://forwardtest33.appspot.com/ .

Your help really need.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planing to serve video only packaged with your app, or stored somewhere in blobstore?

Comment: Your sample app throws a NullPointerException. In any case, you should examine the headers returned by the server to see what the difference is between the methods.